# Reference to primary key with constraints

Tags: sql, primary-key

I have 2 tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE Apartment
(
    StreetName char(50) not null,
    Number Integer not null,
    Door Integer not null,
    Type char(30) not null,
    SizeSquareMeter Integer not null,
    NID Integer not null FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Neighborhood(NID)
    CONSTRAINT Address PRIMARY KEY (StreetName, Number, Door)
);

CREATE TABLE Resident
(
    RID Integer not null PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(30) not null,
    LastName varchar(30) not null,
    BirthDate date not null,
    Address
);
```

Now the primary key in apartment is `Address` and is based on constraint. I want to create a foreign key `Address` in the `Resident` table referencing the 
primary key `Address` in the `Apartment` table.

How can I do that?

Comment: You do not "reference" other constraints, you have to add StreetName,Number,Door to Resident.  I would change this to use a sequence for apartment and add that to Resident similar to what you did with "RID"

Comment: A FK has a column list referencing a column list that forms a PK or UNIQUE key. A key declaration also delcares a constraint that has a(n explicit or implicit) constraint name. A FK doesn't reference a constraint. Read the manual or an introduction to see how you are not following it & how you should follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your primary key in `Apartment` is made up from three columns, any table wanting to reference `Apartment` will **also** need to have **ALL three columns** to establish a foreign key link.

So you need to change your `Resident` table to:

```
CREATE TABLE Resident
(
    RID Integer not null PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(30) not null,
    LastName varchar(30) not null,
    BirthDate date not null,
    StreetName char(50) not null,
    Number Integer not null,
    Door Integer not null,
);
```

and then you can add the foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Resident
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Resident_Apartment
    FOREIGN KEY (StreetName, Number, Door) REFERENCES Apartment (StreetName, Number, Door);
```

The other option would be to add a **surrogate** column (an artificial, additional column) to `Apartment` - either as primary key, or (for SQL Server) at least with a **unique constraint** - so that you could establish the FK link to that surrogate column (using that one, single column - instead of having to replicate three columns of "real" data)

Comment: Re "Since your primary key in Apartment is made up from three columns, any table wanting to reference Apartment will also need to have ALL three columns to establish a foreign key": That isn't true. I guess you mean, wanting to reference that PK in apartment. That still isn't true. If there were a unique constraint on a subset of the PK then one could have a FK to that subset of it. So something like that is true, but not that. Also, the asker is confusing a PK with the associated constraint, see the comments the question.

Comment: @philipxy: yes, **IF** there were a unique constraint on the `Apartment` table, then one could reference that using a FK constraint (at least in SQL Server - the OP isn't clear on what RDBMS he's using). But there's no unique constraint in sight - only the composite PK - so the FK needs to match those columns

Comment: But your sentence doesn't say "and no others". It's "since" is not sound.